# How to have two Array with @Post Construct List in a bean

Tags: java, jsf-2

I need your help in defining two array lists in a bean with @Post Construct. I need to retrieve the values from an array list and to display them in 2 selectmanycheckbox component.

The code is:

```
private String[] selectedA;
private List<String> A;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    A = new ArrayList<String>();
    A.add("A");
    A.add("B");
}

private String[] selectedB;
private List<String> B;

@PostConstruct
public void initBB() {
    B = new ArrayList<String>();
    B.add("C");
    B.add("D");
}
```

However it displays an error if I am using the above way, so can you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need your help in defining two array lists in a bean with @Post Construct.

If I understand it correctly (the class is not complete), you have two methods annotated `@PostConstruct`. Only one is allowed, having more than one will cause some kind of error.

So, use only one `@PostConstruct` method, and initialize both arrays in it:

```
private List<String> a;
private List<String> b;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    a = new ArrayList<String>();
    a.add("A");
    a.add("B");

    b = new ArrayList<String>();
    b.add("C");
    b.add("D");
}
```

The JavaDoc for `@PostConstruct` can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html), it says:

> Only one method can be annotated with this annotation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use two @PostConstruct methods the behavior will be unpredictable.

Ref: http://www.coderanch.com/t/428906/java-EJB-SCBCD/certification/PostConstruct-methods

Try this:

```
private String[] selectedA;
private List<String> A;
private String[] selectedB;
private List<String> B;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    A = new ArrayList<String>();
    A.add("A");
    A.add("B");

    B = new ArrayList<String>();
    B.add("C");
    B.add("D");
}
```

Or if you want two methods for initialize the arrays:

```
private String[] selectedA;
private List<String> A;
private String[] selectedB;
private List<String> B;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    A = new ArrayList<String>();
    A.add("A");
    A.add("B");

    initBB();
}

public void initBB() {
    B = new ArrayList<String>();
    B.add("C");
    B.add("D");
}
```